# Hover over TreeTable does not scroll page

Tags: sapui5

Using openui5 version 1.42.7, when hovering over the TreeTable area the mouse wheel does nothing and the page does not scroll.

In a previous version, 1.32.9, this behavior worked perfectly.

Here is the basic structure of our page.

```
<Page id="page" navButtonPress="onNavBack" showNavButton="false" title="
    {i18n>pageTitle}" busy="{detailView>/busy}" enableScrolling="true"                  
    busyIndicatorDelay="{detailView>/delay}">
   <content>
     <Panel id ="panel" expandable="false" expanded="false" width="auto" visible="true"  
        class="sectionHeaderbackground">
        <IconTabBar id="iconTabBar" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding backgroundFormArea" 
         height="20px" visible="true" select="onSelectChanged"  headerMode="Inline"
         expandable="false">
           <items>
           <IconTabFiter>
              <l:Grid defaultSpan="L8 M8 S8">
                 <l:content>
                    <TreeTable id="TreeTableBasic" select="onSelectNodes" rows="{path:'/hierarchy',
                        parameters: {arrayNames:['children']}}" selectionMode="None"enableSelectAll="true"
                        selected="true" ariaLabelledBy="title" visibleRowCountMode="Fixed">
                         <t:toolbar>
            <Toolbar>
              <Title id="title" text="" />
              <ToolbarSpacer />
              <Button text="{i18n>collapseButton}" press="onCollapseAll" type="Emphasized"
                    icon="sap-icon://collapse" class="buttonColour"/>
              <Button text="{i18n>expandallButton}" press="onExpandAll" type="Emphasized"
                    icon="sap-icon://expand" class="buttonColour"/>
            </Toolbar>
             </t:toolbar>
             <t:columns>
            <t:Column width="13rem">
                <Label text="{i18n>locationTreeTable}" design="Bold"/>
                <t:template>
                   <HBox>
                    <CheckBox selected="{checkValue}" select="locationCheck"></CheckBox>
                    <core:Icon src="sap-icon://group" visible="{= !!${name}}"
                        class="paddingClass" />
                    <Link text="{name}" emphasized="{= !!${locationGroupGUID}}"></Link>
                  </HBox>
                   </t:template>
            </t:Column>
             </t:columns>
        </t:TreeTable>
        </l:content>
    </l:Grid>
    </IconTabFilter>
</items>
 </IconTabBar>
</Panel>
</content>
</Page>
```

There are a few other tags I eliminated for brevity, but they are just for unrelated parts of the page that do not have the scrolling issue.

When I use the Developer tools and delete the [highlighted div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSMXU.png) from the Html the scrolling works when hovering over the TreeTable

I'm not very familiar with openUI5. In fact this code was developed by a consultant. They are saying this is a framework issue and there is nothing they can do about.

I suspect this is a bug that needs to be reported on the openui5 github repository but I wanted to check here before submitting the bug in case there is something that is obviously wrong with how this is implemented.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a work around by redefining the a few of CSS classes in our css file.  By adding the attribute pointer-events:none on the sapUiTableCtrlScr class I was able to scroll on the Table.

```
.sapUiTableTreeIcon {
    display: none;
    width: 25px;
    padding: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    margin-right: 6px;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

The value none sends the mouse event to the element behind the targeted element with this value. Doing this maybe the checkbox and collapse and expand buttons not work so I had to add the pointer-events:auto in the sapUiTableTreeIcon and sapMCb classes.

```
.sapUiTableTreeIcon {
    display: none;
    width: 25px;
    padding: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    margin-right: 6px;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.sapMCb {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 3rem;
    line-height: 3rem;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 0 0 3rem;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```